# JavaScript, Pressing the enter key

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript assignment is a ''to-do list', the user needs to be able to press the enter key, I tried this code but it's not working. If anyone has suggestions please let me know! Thanks

EDIT: Here is my JavaScript, HTML and CSS file

EDIT II: Here are the directions in full
1. After inserting a new item, clear the input field
2. If the user presses the enter key, perform the same action as clicking the plus button.
3. Check to make sure that the user entered something into the input field adding it to the list
4. When the user clicks on the heading, so a prompt to allow them to change the title. Make sure they entered something before changing it.
[image: The output]

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
 
 var todos = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');
 var removes = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
 document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
 document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', toggleCompleted, false);
 document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);
 
 function toggleCompleted(e) {
  console.log('=' + e.target.className);
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('todo-item') < 0) {
   return;
  }
  console.log(e.target.className.indexOf('completed'));
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('completed') > -1) {
   console.log(' ' + e.target.className);
   e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(' completed', '');
  } else {
   console.log('-' + e.target.className);
   e.target.className += ' completed';   
  }
 }
 
 function addItem() {
  var list = document.querySelector('ul.todo-list');
  var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-text').value;
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.className = 'todo-item';
  newListItem.innerHTML = newItem + '<span class="remove"></span>';
  list.insertBefore(newListItem, document.querySelector('.todo-new'));
  
 }
 
 function valueField(input,val){
 if(input.value == "")
   input.value=val;
  
 }
 
 function clearField(input,val){
  if(input.value == val)
   input.value="";
 }
 
 function removeItem(e) {
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('remove') < 0) {
   return;
  }
  
 function handle(e){
  var keycode 
  if(e.keyCode === ""){
   }
  return false;
 }
  var el = e.target.parentNode;
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
 }
 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #BCDBF2;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body > div {
  width: 300px;
  margin:50px auto;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

.todo-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.todo-item {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.todo-new {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.todo-new input[type='text'] {
  width: 260px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

.todo-new a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.todo-new a:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0dd;
}

.remove {
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #dd0000;
}

.remove:before {
  content: 'X';
}

.remove:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.todo-item::after:hover{
  background-color: #dd0000;
  color: white;
}

.todo-item:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0FF;
  color: white;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Lab 18 - Event Delegation</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'/>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <ul class='todo-list'>
   <li class='todo-item'>4L 2% Milk
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-item'>Butter, Unsalted
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-item'>Dozen Eggs
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-item'>Walk the dog
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-item'>Cut the lawn
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-item'>Laundry
    <span class='remove'></span></li>
   <li class='todo-new'>
    <input id='new-item-text' type='text'/>
    <a id='add-item' href='#'>+</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the code to do?  Right now it checks to see if the keyCode is empty, and if true, it does nothing.

Comment: Look up the keycode for the enter key.  It's not `""`

Comment: the keycode of `enter` is 13

Comment: The instructions say "If the user presses the enter key, perform the same action as clicking the plus button"

Comment: Remember to run addEventListener for your new handle() function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the key code for enter is 13. See below.

```
function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ask the OP. I didn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the key code that will correspond to enter. One place to find this is on [MDN KeyboardEvent:keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Using that, you can write:

```
var ENTER = 13;
function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === ENTER){
      // insert a new line or whatever you want
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the **onkeypress** event on a **HTML element**, for example on the input text, like this:

```
<input id='new-item-text' type='text' onkeypress="return handle(event)" />
```

Also, you can register the event on `<body>`or other HTML elements. And you can register the event using HTML or using Javascript.

### In HTML:

```
<element onkeypress="myScript">
```

### In JavaScript:

```
object.onkeypress=function(){myScript};
```

If you want to learn more about this event you can read [**this docs**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp).

To know where is the `handle` function needs to be global *(declared outside the load event)*.

The last thing to do, is to filter the <kbd>enter</kbd> button with `e.keyCode === 13`. Important: **is a Number**, not a String.

I put below all the code testable that you can see and run (I applied the example when press <kbd>enter</kbd> on the input text).

I hope to help you.

---

### All the code

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var todos = document.getElementsByClassName('todo-item');
  var removes = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
  document.getElementById('add-item').addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
  document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', toggleCompleted, false);
  document.querySelector('.todo-list').addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);

  function toggleCompleted(e) {
    console.log('=' + e.target.className);
    if (e.target.className.indexOf('todo-item') < 0) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(e.target.className.indexOf('completed'));
    if (e.target.className.indexOf('completed') > -1) {
      console.log(' ' + e.target.className);
      e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(' completed', '');
    } else {
      console.log('-' + e.target.className);
      e.target.className += ' completed';
    }
  }

  function addItem() {
    var list = document.querySelector('ul.todo-list');
    var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-text').value;
    var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
    newListItem.className = 'todo-item';
    newListItem.innerHTML = newItem + '<span class="remove"></span>';
    list.insertBefore(newListItem, document.querySelector('.todo-new'));

  }

  function valueField(input, val) {
    if (input.value == "")
      input.value = val;

  }

  function clearField(input, val) {
    if (input.value == val)
      input.value = "";
  }

  function removeItem(e) {
    if (e.target.className.indexOf('remove') < 0) {
      return;
    }

    var el = e.target.parentNode;
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }

});

function handle(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log("Doing something");
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #BCDBF2;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body > div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.todo-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.todo-item {
  border: 2px solid #444;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.todo-new {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.todo-new input[type='text'] {
  width: 260px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}
.todo-new a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.todo-new a:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0dd;
}
.remove {
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #dd0000;
}
.remove:before {
  content: 'X';
}
.remove:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.todo-item::after:hover {
  background-color: #dd0000;
  color: white;
}
.todo-item:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0FF;
  color: white;
}
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lab 18 - Event Delegation</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css' />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    <ul class='todo-list'>
      <li class='todo-item'>4L 2% Milk
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-item'>Butter, Unsalted
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-item'>Dozen Eggs
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-item'>Walk the dog
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-item'>Cut the lawn
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-item'>Laundry
        <span class='remove'></span>
      </li>
      <li class='todo-new'>
        <input id='new-item-text' type='text' onkeypress="return handle(event)" />
        <a id='add-item' href='#'>+</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```